# Is this considered combinations of combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

Excuse my ignorance but I know so little about the topic that Im not even sure how to phrase my question.  Ok, so most online combination generators will create lists of combinations of *n* length from a given set.  What do I need to do if I want to take the result of these combinations and combine them all together.

For example, let's say we're talking about people and I want to create a list of combinations of different sets:

- gender (male, female)
- ethnicity (Caucasian, Hispanic, African, Native American, Asian / Pacific Islander, Other)
- height (short, average, tall)
- age (0-18, 19-22, 23-40, 41-64, 64+)

What kind of combinatorics are we talking about here and is there an online calculator out there that can generate that list for me?

Comment: This is simply repeated application of the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  You have two options for gender, six options for ethnicity, three options for height, etc... making the total number of possible outcomes the product of the number of choices at each step: $2\times 6\times 3\times \cdots$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  How can I generate the actual list, which is what I'm more interested in than the number of outcomes?

Comment: The full list of possible outcomes would be the entries in the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) $\{male,~female\}\times \{caucasian,~hispanic,~\dots,~other\}\times\{short,\dots\}\times \dots$

Comment: If you are looking for an algorithm to actually generate the list... just do it in lexicographic order.  You know how to list numbers I assume... say for example the numbers in base 3 being $000,001,002,010,011,012,020,\dots,333$... the exact same process can be used here, just each position is instead whatever the corresponding set of options are, i.e. (male, caucasian, short, 0-18), (male, caucasian, short, 19-22), ... (male, caucasian, short, 64+), (male, caucasian, average, 0-18),...,..., (female, other, tall, 64+)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot or the help but you've lost me on the last one.  At least I've learned what I need to be looking for which is ... a cartesian product calculator?  But the ones I've found online so far are limited to two sets.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use a calculator for this.  Just start with the "smallest" outcome for each slot.  Then go to the "next" outcome in the list for the final position until you reach the last one available, at which point the following that you write will instead increase the second to last and you revert the final down again.  Using decimal numbers as the example then since maybe base 3 isn't your thing... 000, (*increase final repeatedly*)  001, 002, 003, ..., 008, 009 (*we reached the end for the final, so increase one before it and go back to zero*), 010, (*repeat*) 011, 012...

Comment: Eventually, the second to last position will reach it's end too:  ......, 088, 089, 090, 091,..., 098, 099, (*we reached end for last, so revert to zero, but we also reached end for second to last as well, so revert that to zero and increase previous by one*) 100, 101, 102, 103, ...     The process is as I say, *identical* when using words instead of numbers.  The only difference is flavor.  If you can't count to 1000 with numbers, I think your question should be about that instead of your original question.

Comment: In Python, the package `itertools` has the method `product` which computes the Cartesian product of any number of lists.

Comment: https://www.twjc.co.uk/combinations.html

Comment: @MattWatkins pay attention to what is being discussed.  The utility you link to clearly has nothing to do with cartesian products and is not useful to the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for their input, it ended up being extremely useful because, first of all, I learned that what we are talking about is Cartesian products so at least I now know what to Google for more information.  Thanks to @JMoravitz for that.  And thanks to @Mike Earnest for recommending itertools.  I ended up writing this simple Python script to do the work for me:

```
import itertools

sets = [
   ['male','female'],
   ['white','black','latino','american indian','asian','other'],
   ['short','average','tall'],
   ['0-18','19-22','23-40','41-64','64+']
]
for element in itertools.product(*sets):
    print(element)
```